# Can I apply enumeration to a schema element only in specific situations?

Tags: xml, schema, enumeration

In my XML Schema, I have an element that looks like this:

```
 <xs:element name="food">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:sequence id="vegetables">
          <xs:element ref="name"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="texture"/>
          <xs:element ref="image"/>
          <xs:element ref="color"/>                       
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence id="fruit">
          <xs:element ref="description"/>
          <xs:element ref="seeds"/>
          <xs:element ref="color"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

As you can see, `color` appears in both sequences. Is it possible to only enumerate values in one of these sequences, even if I use the element name `color` for both? As in, if it's a vegetable I would like to restrict the potential values of color to red, orange, and green, where for the fruits I'd like it to be fully free text. If it helps, within the files these have unique xpaths, ie:

```
<record>
    <fruit>
        <food>
            <description>Apple</description>
            <seeds>Make tree grow inside you</seeds>
            <color>It depends</color>
        </food>
    </fruit>
    <vegetable>
        <food>
            <name>Carrot</name>
            <texture>Crunchy</texture>
            <image>file.jpeg</image>
            <color>Orange</color>
        </food>
    </vegetable>
</record>
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule in XSD called "element declarations consistent" that says, in effect, that if two sibling elements have the same name then they must have the same type. So the basic answer is NO.

With XSD 1.1, however, you can add an assertion at the level of the `food` element that says "if element `name` exists then `colour` must be one of X, Y or Z" - so rather than defining the enumeration as a property of the colour element, you define a cross-element constraint on the containing element.

Comment: This is very helpful, but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to write the correct test statement. I've got something like `test="if (record/fruit/food/color) then color/$value=('orange'|'green')"` but I know that that's not the right way to get it to test the XPath, having a lot of trouble googling exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: If the assertion is on "food", then it's `test="if (exists(name)) then color=('red', 'orange', 'green') else true()"`. However, I'm not sure, because your schema allows `<food><name/><image/><color/><decsription/><seeds/><color/></food>` and I've no idea what that would mean.

Comment: Just wanted to say I really appreciated your help here. The good news is I convinced the people who make decisions that having a `color` tag that meant different things in different situations was a mistake and they should let me just change the name of that element and enumerate it the regular way. (Though obviously my real schema is not about food.)